# RenameColumn not working at EF Core Code-First Migration - with MySql (AWS Aurora)

Tags: c#, mysql, code-first, ef-core-2.2, amazon-aurora

I am using those below packages for using MySql(AWS Aurora) from .Net Core project:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.2.4" />
<PackageReference Include="MySql.Data" Version="8.0.16" />
<PackageReference Include="MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.16" />
```

It's working fine but, when I have a scenario to **rename** a **column** then I got a problem. It's not working.

Migration file creation working fine. Its contain "**RenameColumn**":

```
migrationBuilder.RenameColumn(
                name: "SecretKey",
                table: "Company",
                newName: "Password");
```

Problem is when run the **Update-database** command it not working, gave this below error:

> System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(RenameColumnOperation operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(MigrationOperation operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(IReadOnlyList`1 operations, IModel model)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.GenerateUpSql(Migration migration)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)

I have manually changed this "RenameColumn" into two parts **DropColumn** & **AddColumn**. It's working temporarily.

Any suggestions?